# Missing libpopt library when building GPT fdisk

Tags: macos, linker, osx-elcapitan

I saw [this guide](http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Installazione/UbuntuMacIntel) for install ubuntu on Mac. 
I try to install GPT fdisk but this it isn't compatible with 10.11.
I compile the source code from [the official web site](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/)
with the command `make -f Makefile.mac` but missing the libraries.
I must install XCode and MacPorts, but I still have an error:

> g++ crc32.o support.o guid.o gptpart.o mbrpart.o basicmbr.o mbr.o
>   gpt.o bsd.o parttypes.o attributes.o diskio.o diskio-unix.o gptcl.o
>   sgdisk.o -L/sw/lib -lpopt -o sgdisk
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/sw/lib'
>
> ld: library not found for -lpopt clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [sgdisk] Error
>   1<

How to resolve? 
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This question belongs on askubuntu.com

Comment: I've just retracted my close vote, which was a knee-jerk reaction to the "cannot install ubuntu" in your title.  That title is misleading as you are actually asking an on-topic question about linker errors/missing libraries.

Comment: It looks like you haven't installed MacPorts properly (or at least the required packages) - MacPorts creates the /sw directory and installs includes and libraries there.

Comment: @PaulR That's news to me.  Everything is normally installed into `/opt/local`,

Comment: @Droppy - ah my bad - maybe I misremembered - perhaps it's fink that uses /sw ?

Comment: Yeah it rings a bell, but I think it's obsolete now.  The answer is to install macports and edit that `Makefile`, however, I'm not sure I have the energy to explain all that's required.

Comment: @Droppy: [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) seems to be the easiest solution - see below...

Comment: Yeah I've always preferred macports though; I believe it has more ports and I don't have a problem with the workflow.

Comment: @Droppy: over the years I've been through fink, MacPorts and Homebrew (in that order), and find Homebrew the easiest and most reliable, but YMMV - I do sometimes go back to MacPorts if I can't find it on Homebrew, I admit.

Answer (score 2):

No need to build this from scratch - just install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and `gptfdisk` is available as a ready-made formula:

```
$ brew info gptfdisk
gptfdisk: stable 1.0.0 (bottled)
Text-mode partitioning tools
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/gptfdisk.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: popt ✔, icu4c ✔
$ sudo brew install gptfdisk
Password:
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gptfdisk-1.0.0_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring gptfdisk-1.0.0_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/gptfdisk/1.0.0_1: 12 files, 868K
$
```

And that's all there is to it.

Comment: [SOLVED] I run :
make -f Makefile.mac clean
make -f Makefile.mac gdisk

and it work!! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With recent Homebrew, since formulae has been removed from core you have to do:

```
brew install homebrew/boneyard/gptfdisk
```

Than you can find the binaries in `/usr/local/sbin`.
Since sbin was no linked in my system path (don't know why) I had to add it manually with:

```
sudo vim /etc/paths
```

and adding the line

```
/usr/local/sbin
```